# How can I duplicate the UI functionality of Google Fastflip?

Tags: javascript, image, image-manipulation

Trying to get the same functionality as [Google FastFlip](http://fastflip.googlelabs.com). Not just with the thumbnails, but even for the larger images too.

Notice how when you click on a story, you see the main story front and center, and you see smaller half-screens of previous and next stories.

How can I get that functionality? Is there a plugin for one of the JS frameworks that does this already?

I also love the speed and feel of flipping through the images.

Answer (score -1):

Look at jquery.  It's a good first step.